# IIS 7.5 HTTPS Stopped working

Tags: azure, ssl, iis

This may look like a duplicate, but I can't find anything else to try. 
The Wildcard SSL (Only 1 month old) was installed fine and everything was going swimmingly until today I noticed it was redirecting to HTTP. Any attempts to remove HTTP bindings or force to HTTPS have only drawn a server not found.

This is happening for the stock domain and also the subdomains.

Nothing's changed. The server has been restarted during the period prior to the issue, the cert seems fine, it's also apparently fine in the server setup. I did not drag and drop the cert between stores. The Azure endpoint is in place. Firewall is good. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your website hosted on an Azure VM or Azure App Service WebApps? If it’s the latter, App Service does not enforce HTTPS, so anyone can still access your web app using HTTP. To enforce HTTPS for your web app, define a rewrite rule in the web.config file for your web app. App Service uses this file, regardless of the language framework of your web app.

Comment: No sorry it's on a VM.